# JQUERY. Menu Toggle help required

Tags: jquery

I have a horizontal navigation of `<li>`'s which on click I would like to have the child `ul` drop down. I have managed to do this, but when you click on the next `<li>` it does not close the previous.

Here is my code:

```
$("#menu-flag-menu li a").click(function(){
    var ul = $(this).next("ul");
    if (ul.is(":hidden")) {
        ul.slideToggle();
    } else {
        ul.slideToggle();
    }
});
```

The HTML is:

```
<div class="menu-flag-menu-container">
<ul id="menu-flag-menu" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-138""><a href="">DPSS 1064nm</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-135" class=""><a href="">Starlase AO2</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-135" class=""><a href="">Starlase AO2</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-135" class=""><a href="">Starlase AO2</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-135" class=""><a href="">Starlase AO2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-138""><a href="">DPSS 1064nm</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-135" class=""><a href="">Starlase AO2</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-135" class=""><a href="">Starlase AO2</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-135" class=""><a href="">Starlase AO2</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-135" class=""><a href="">Starlase AO2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-138""><a href="">DPSS 1064nm</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-135" class=""><a href="">Starlase AO2</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-135" class=""><a href="">Starlase AO2</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-135" class=""><a href="">Starlase AO2</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-135" class=""><a href="">Starlase AO2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#menu-flag-menu li a").click(function(){ 

    // close all opened sub menus
    $("#menu-flag-menu > li > ul").slideUp();

    var ul = $(this).next("ul");     
    ul.slideToggle(); 
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/XaLER/2/

Updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/XaLER/3/

Comment: This works apart from when you click on the active `<li>' is does not collapse that drop down